# How to use nsicookieservice to get cookie-changed list

Tags: android, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I've been reading the [MDN docs about nsicookieservice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieService) and I'm interested in the notifications of this service: cookie-changed and cookie-rejected. Does that mean that we can get a list of the changed or rejected cookies? Would that be possible by doing somthing like this:

```
    var cookieSvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookieService;1"]
              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieService);
    var cookies=cookieSvc.cookie-changed;
```

Thank you for the explanation.

I reread the documentation(I really did) and searched in the source codes of many extensions. The problem that the extension that i'm building is bootstarpped for firefox for android but I'm not using SDK. Based on what I understood I wrote this:

```
  var cookieMonster = {
//cookieManager: null,
current: null,
observerService: null,
cookieService: null,
init: function() {
this.observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
this.observerService.addObserver(this, "cookie-changed", false);
this.cookieService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookieService;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieService);
//  this.cookieManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager);
},
uninit: function() {
//var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
this.observerService.removeObserver(this, "cookie-changed", false);
//this.cookieManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager);
},
observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
    if (topic != 'cookie-changed') { this.current= "no cookie changed"; return; }
    try {
    //  if (!ghostery.prefs.cookieProtect) { return; }
    this.current="there is a chnged cookie!!!";
    if ( (data == 'added') || (data == 'changed') ) {
    var cookie = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsICookie2);
    this.current = "name "+cookie.name+" host "+cookie.host;
        }
    } catch (err) {}
  }
    };
```

Then I do this to add the observer when I load the page:

```
    let addListener = function() {
    window.BrowserApp.deck.addEventListener("load", cookieMonster.init, false);
    window.NativeWindow.toast.show(cookieMonster.current, "long");
    };
    if(window.BrowserApp.deck) {
    // BrowserApp.deck (and maybe whole BrowserApp?) has been initialized
    addListener();
    }
    else {
    // use the chrome window to wait for BrowserApp to initialize
    window.BrowserApp.deck.addEventListener("UIReady", addListener);
    }
```

That doesn't work and I don't find any error in the logcat which confuse me more.I'm really stuck and I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your add-on can receive notifications about cookies, but you don't receive them via the cookies manager, but the general purpose `nsIObserverService`.

- XUL overlay add-ons should use the [`nsIObserverService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService) directly.
- SDK add-ons will want to use the [`system/events`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/system/events.html) module instead, which is a bit higher level and does clean up after itself.

There is also [a list of the most commonly used notification types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have questions how to call the observer: should i call the observe method in function fired by the "load" event (an eventListener)? And about the parameters of this method, should i pass values or they will be captured by the observer? I added an example of observe method taken from cookieMonster addon to show you what I'm talking about. Sorry my questions are maybe stupid, but it's really confusing me.

Comment: You got it the wrong way around: *You* have to implement an observer (`observe` method) and register that with the service. The service will then call *your* `observe` method when cookies change. Re-read the documentation.

Comment: I know that I have to add the observer to the observerService then to remove it later, but do i do that when i load and unload the page to get the wanted results? Is the serviceOserver the one who handles the observe method?